# Python selenium - InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Tags: python

I'm trying to start webscraping, I can access URL but whenever I try to send something to an element I get an error message.

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(video)
  File "C:\Users\Lam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\Lam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Lam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument:
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

Could anyone tell me what's happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of `video` in the call to `.send_keys(video)`?

Comment: is abs path of a file, I think that is string@JustinEzequiel

Comment: Do not guess. Do a `print(type(video))`

Comment: yes it is a string@JustinEzequiel